# Display symbol over marker in plotly legend

Tags: r, plotly

How can I update the legend in this plot so that the legend has the symbol over the marker instead of after the maker. The current text in the legend should be replaced by these values: `c(increase = "+", decrease = "-", unknown = "?")`

```
library(plotly)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 0, text = c("?", "+", "-"))
plot_ly() |>
  add_trace(
    x = ~x, y = ~y, text = ~text, color = ~text, data = df,
    type = "scatter", mode = "markers+text",
    marker = list(size = 20), textfont = list(size = 12, color = "white")
  )
```

[image: Output from code above]

Answer (score 0):

I only came across your question yesterday; it sounded very interesting! I can think of two methods of accomplishing this.

1. Using Plotly, hide the legend and rebuild the legend manually using `layout.shapes` and `layout.annotations`.
2. Using `htmlwidgets::onRender` and JS/JQuery.

I think there is a lot more code necessary to use the Plotly-only method, so I went down the JS path. I've got two possible solutions for you.

In the first, the plot is modified to move the symbols on top of the legend icons. In the second, I've used the info you provided: increase, decrease, unknown, and added that info to the legend along with moving the symbols.

###### Symbol move only

This is what happens in the JS:

- Capture the x or horizontal position of an icon/symbol in the legend
- For each legend entry

  - Clone the current text element
  - Modify the cloned element: center, x-position, color
  - Add the cloned text element to the icon/symbol

```
plot_ly() |>
  add_trace(
    x = ~x, y = ~y, text = ~text, color = ~text, data = df,
    type = "scatter", mode = "markers+text",
    marker = list(size = 20), textfont = list(size = 12, color = "white")
  ) %>% 
  htmlwidgets::onRender(
    "function(el, x) {                               /* extract transform val */
      newX = $('path.scatterpts').attr('transform').match(/(?<=\\()\\d+/g)[0];
      $('text.legendtext').clone().each(function(ind) {       /* create clone */
                                              /* mod text clone & add to symb */
          cl = $(this).attr({'x': newX, 'text-anchor': 'middle'})
                      .css('fill', 'white');
          
          $('g.legendpoints')[ind].append(cl[0]); /* add new txt elem to plot */
      })
    }")
```

If you wanted to remove the text to the right of the of the icon/symbol, just remove `.clone()` from `$('text.legendtext').clone().each(function(ind)` (so it's `...text').each(f...`)
[image]

###### Symbol move and relabel legend entries

First, I added your labels to the data.

```
df2 <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 0, text = c("?", "+", "-"), 
                  symb = c("unknown", "increase", "decrease"))
```

In the plot, I added `name = ~symb`.
In the JS, the only difference from above is the addition of `.text(x.data[ind].text)` to the modifications of the cloned text element.

```
plot_ly() |>
  add_trace(
    x = ~x, y = ~y, text = ~text, color = ~text, data = df2,
    type = "scatter", mode = "markers+text", name = ~symb,
    marker = list(size = 20), textfont = list(size = 12, color = "white")
  ) %>% 
  htmlwidgets::onRender(
    "function(el, x) {                               /* extract transform val */
      newX = $('path.scatterpts').attr('transform').match(/(?<=\\()\\d+/g)[0];
      $('text.legendtext').clone().each(function(ind) {       /* create clone */
                                              /* mod text clone & add to symb */
          cl = $(this).attr({'x': newX, 'text-anchor': 'middle'})
                      .css('fill', 'white')
                      .text(x.data[ind].text);           /* add symbols + - ? */
          
          $('g.legendpoints')[ind].append(cl[0]); /* add new txt elem to plot */
      })
    }")
```

[image]